# Are logical connectors and quantifiers just another term for operators in the logic programming paradigm?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I am learning about the logic programming paradigm and my professor talks about quantifiers and logical connectors in propositions. Are these not just operators to use on propositions? I do not see my professor call them operators, is there some sort of reason for that, or they could be classified as operators in logic programming paradigm?

Comment: Not knowing who your professor is, or how she is using these terms, that would be very difficult to answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter How do you know it's a "she"?

Comment: @TA_intern: Would you have even *considered* commenting if I had used "he"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Not sure. I just re-read the question like 5 times and wondered if I am missing a subtle clue. Also, we don't have genders in my native tongue, only one word for he/she/it (if it is a person) and actually in spoken language people even use the same word for he/she/it (person) and it (object).

Comment: @ScottHunter and in three other languages I know, "professor" would actually be gendered itself. So you cannot talk about a person (with some small exceptions) without explicitly saying their gender. German and Slavic languages are like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Prolog (as opposed to some full First Order Logic prover), [operator](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators) is a technical term for predicate or function names that can be written before, after or in between subexpressions.

These indeed include the "*and*" (`,`) the "*or*" (`;`) the "*classical/material implication*" (`:-`) read as *head ⊂ body* (but it's actually the [intuitionistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) implication because it says "to prove the head, prove the body", and *not* "the body is false or the head is true"), and the *if-then-else* (based on two operators `->`, `;`), among others.

There are **no explicitly written quantifiers** - every clause is implicitly universally quantified over all its variables (variables are local to each clause)

For clause

```
f(X,Y) :- g(X,Z),h(Z,Y).
```

read

```
∀(X,Y,Z): f(X,Y) :- g(X,Z),h(Z,Y).
```

All the existential quantifiers have been eliminated beforehand via [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), whereby existentially quantified variables are replaced by (fresh) constants, possibly inside function terms. (There is a little leftover of ∃ in the `^` (caret) operator used in higher order predicates like [`bagof/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3), where `X^...` is used to create a "local naming context" and restrict `X` to the expression following the `^`).